# Showing $C[-1,1] $ with a certain inner product is not complete

Tags: real-analysis

> **Problem.**
>   Show that $C[-1,1]$, the set of continuous functions on $[-1,1]$, with the inner product
>   $$\langle f, g\rangle = \int _{-1} ^1 f(x)g(x) \, dx$$
>   is not a Hilbert space over $\mathbb{R}$ by considering the sequence
>   $$f_n(x)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
>              1, &      x \in [-1,0] 
>              \\ 1-nx, &     x \in ( 0,\frac{1}{n} ] 
>              \\ 0, &     x \in ( \frac{1}{n},1] .
>              \end{array}
>    \right.$$

My attempt.

If we can show that ${f_n}$ is Cauchy, the result will follow. Let $\epsilon >0$ and suppose $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$ with $ n>m$. Then
\begin{align*}
||f_n - f_m||^2 = \langle f_n - f_m \rangle \langle f_n - f_m \rangle &=
\int _{-1} ^{1} (f_n - f_m)(f_n - f_m) \, dx \\&
= \int_0 ^{1/n} (m-n)^2 x^2 \, dx + \int _{1/n} ^{1/m} (1-mx)^2 \, dx \\&
=\frac{(m-n)^2}{3n^3} + \frac{1}{3m} \left( \frac{m}{n} - 1 \right) ^3 \\&=
\frac{(m-n)^2}{3n^3} +  \frac{(m-n)^3}{3mn^3} \\&<
\frac{m^2}{3n^3} +  \frac{m^3}{3mn^3} \\&=
\frac{2m^2}{3n^3} \\&<
\frac{2m^2}{3n} \\&<
\frac{2m^2}{3m} \\&=
\frac{2}{3} m \\&<
m .
\end{align*}
It would be great if I could have $m < \epsilon ^2$, but this seems strange for me to have (in the typical process of showing a sequence is Cauchy, we choose a "clever" choice of $N$ so that for all $n>m \geq N$ we have some sort of condition. In this case, it seems like we would say choose $N$ so that $m < \epsilon ^2$, but that sounds off to me). Please let me know how to proceed or if my proof went astray along the way, and how I can improve it. (If there is a different sequence you can come up with that seems more simple, please let me know that as well. I am just practicing problems as a self-study.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $n >m$ the $f_n(x)=f_m(x)$ as long as $x \notin (0, \frac 1 m)$. So $\int |f_n-f_m|^{2}=\int_{0}^{\frac  1m} |f_n-f_m|^{2} \leq \frac 1 m \to 0$ because if two numbers lie in $[0,1]$ then their difference is at most $1$. [The numbers I am referring to are $f_n(x)$ and $f_m(x)$].

If $f_n \to f$ in this space then there is a subsequence which converges almost everywhere. But then $f(x)=1$ almost everywhere on $[-1,0]$ and $0$ almost everywhere on $[0,1]$ which rules out continuity of $f$ Hence the space is not complete.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Kavi. But why is $f_n(x) = f_m (x)$ on $(0, \frac{1}{n})$? If $n>m$, the line segment that $f_n$ represents hits the $x$-axis sooner than the line segment that $f_m$ represents, does it not? (In symbols, $\frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{m}$.) If this is correct, then we would have to integrate on that interval.

Comment: @Compact Answer edited.